# Combine multiple images together

Tags: r

I'm trying to merge multiples images (500 pics) together in a `for` loop. The image size is constant and even not too big (225*410 px). What I need is to obtain a single image composed by the 500 initial pics stuck together side by side.

I've tried with a `for` loop using some functions of package EBImage. `abind()` it's like the traditional `rbind()`. The code I've used is the following:

```r
library(abind)
#path=a list containing the paths of the source images
final_image<-readImage(path[1]) #initialize the final image
for (i in 2:500){
  im <- readImage(path[i]) #open the i-esim image
  final_image <- abind(final_image,im,along=1) #paste the i-esim image with the previous one
}
```

The code works but, obviously, it's really slow because at each iteration the size of `final_image` gets bigger.

Does anyone know a faster workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, iteratively `rbind`ing (goes for other `*bind` funcs, too) is a really bad idea, as it makes a complete copy with each iteration in the loop (as you noticed). Notice that in [`?abind`](https://rdrr.io/cran/abind/man/abind.html), it takes `...`:

```
...  Any number of vectors, matrices, arrays, or data frames. The
     dimensions of all the arrays must match, except on one dimension
     (specified by along=). If these arguments are named, the name will be
     used for the name of the dimension along which the arrays are joined.
     Vectors are treated as having a dim attribute of length one.
```

which allows us to use `do.call` to do the binding all at once on a single list of all images. Try this (untested):

```r
list_of_images <- lapply(path, readImage)
combined <- do.call(abind, c(list_of_images, list(along = 1)))
```